# Permalink "Day and Name" issues with Wordpress and Apache VirtualHosts 404 Error

Tags: wordpress, apache, http-status-code-404, virtualhost, permalinks

I can't for the life of me figure out getting Wordpress to work with pretty permalinks on my Apache server.  I've searched online and tried a myriad of combinations of things.  The URL in question is [www.trixiebangbang.com](http://www.trixiebangbang.com).  I have a traditional LAMP stack running on Ubuntu all hosted with AWS.

I want the Wordpress "Day and Name" permalinks working.  I have already selected that in Wordpress and updated my .htaccess file and given it 755 permissions:

```
# .htaccess file
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That still results in a 404 error when I view my blog posts.  For example if I go to [this example blog post](http://www.trixiebangbang.com/2016/02/22/abc/) it doesn't work.  I then updated my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf configuration file to be the following:

```
# 000-default.conf file
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I am very careful and sure to execute "sudo service apache2 restart" after every change I make before testing.  Can someone please tell me what's wrong here?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After more searching I was able to piece together a solution that worked for me.  I updated the 000-default.conf file to the following and restarted the server.  I hope this helps someone else.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName trixiebangbang.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: `AllowOverride All` on the correct folder would actually be sufficient. You probably have a more global directive in `httpd.conf` on `/var/www/html` and you now overwrite it in the vhost. It's overkill and you could just have patched it in the global config.